# How to use file system functions in EJS?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Day 1 of starting out with NodeJS and EJS and I don't understand how to tackle getting the `mdate` (modified date) of a file and add it as a string to the end of a file reference in EJS.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<link href="/css/mystylesheet.css?v=<%= mdate of mystylesheet.css %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am using the above link plus other stuff in a partial view file called `htmlhead.ejs` which I want to include in all views.

How can I get the file modified date of the `mystylesheet.css` file appended to the `href` attribute so it would be something like this (showing how I currently do it in ColdFusion code):

```
 <link href="/css/mystylesheet.css?v=#DateTimeFormat(GetFileInfo(ExpandPath('/css/mystylesheet.css')).lastmodified, 'yymmddhhnnss')#" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Which outputs to the browser as:

```
<link href="/css/mystylesheet.css?v=20191106104000" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am using ExpressJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to read your file status than you send it to your HTML. But don't forget if you don't have cache and if you have a big file, it could affect your load performance.

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const stats = fs.statSync("/dir/file.txt");
const html = ejs.render('<link href="/css/mystylesheet.css?v=<%= time %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />', {time:stats.mtime.getTime()} );
```

Comment: thanks hurricane. do I put the above code directly in the `htmlhead.ejs` file within a code block like `<% const html = ejs.render('<link href="/css/mystylesheet.css?v=<%= time %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />', {time:stats.mtime.getTime()} ); %>`

Comment: @volumeone depends on your structure. So it is good to follow this repo https://github.com/bhanushalimahesh3/node-website . So you can have better understanding.